# If I add tags to a deployed pipeline (AWS CodePipeline) will the resources deployed through that pipeline inherit those tags?

Tags: boto3, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to code this using BOTO3 but not sure if the tags will be propagated to the resources. I read the AWS documentation and it doesn't appear to mention anything of the sort.

The only information I found on AWS states that, "Applying a tag to a pipeline also propagates the tags to its underlying resources (for example, Amazon EMR clusters and Amazon EC2 instances)" - but this information is under Data Pipeline which I think is different to a code pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe tags are added to the resources within aws-codepipeline unless explicitily stated.

See example 1 & 2 in this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tag-based-access-control.html

`"Resource": "*"` means any resource created when the codepipeline is created. If you are wanting to create IAM policies based on tags the examples in there should help you.

Comment: I did end up testing it by tagging a pipeline, and unfortunately pipeline tags do not propagate to it's resources.